# Got error while constructing the dynamic query

Tags: apex, batch, query

I was trying to build a query to pass it in the QueryLocator. The following is the code snippet I tried to generate the dynamic query,

```
public String buildQueryString(Object_Rule__mdt ObjectRule, Datetime createdDatetime) {
    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    Set<String> statusSetStrings = new Set<String>{'Pending', 'Processing'};
    this.query = 'SELECT ';
    for (Field_Rule__mdt fieldRules : ObjectRule.Field_Rules__r) {
        fields.add(fieldRules.Field_Name__c);
    }

    this.query += String.join(fields, ', ') + ', ' + ContactIdField__c + ' FROM ' + ObjectRule.SObject__c + ' WHERE ' + ObjectRule.ContactIdField__c
            + ' IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Request__c WHERE Status__c IN :statusSetStrings AND CreatedDate < :createdDatetime)';

    return this.query;
}
```

When I tried the above query in a Batch then the batch is returned the error as 'Variable does not exist :statusSetStrings' I was trying to change the query as without the ':' as well before statusSetStrings.

What did I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Apex binding in a dynamic query, you need to think about the idea of *scope*: where is a variable name visible? In what scope does it exist? Let's look at just the skeleton of your code:

```
public String buildQueryString(Object_Rule__mdt ObjectRule, Datetime createdDatetime) {
    Set<String> statusSetStrings = new Set<String>{'Pending', 'Processing'};
    this.query = 'SELECT ';
    this.query += String.join(fields, ', ') + ', ' + ContactIdField__c + ' FROM ' + ObjectRule.SObject__c + ' WHERE ' + ObjectRule.ContactIdField__c
            + ' IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Request__c WHERE Status__c IN :statusSetStrings AND CreatedDate < :createdDatetime)';

    return this.query;
}
```

Notice that `statusSetStrings` has *local scope* - it's a variable declared in this method, and it goes *out of scope* and no longer exists after the closing bracket of the method.

Why does that make a difference? It's because when you construct and return this query, you haven't yet invoked the "magic" part of Apex bindings. Right now, `this.query` is just a `String` that contains the substring `:statusSetStrings`. That substring has no special meaning to Apex until you actually issue the dynamic query with `Database.query()`.

Once you do perform the query, all of those variable bindings are looked up in the local scope *where the query is executed* - not where it is constructed. Put shortly, `statusSetStrings` has to be in scope where the query is executed.

An easy fix, since `statusSetStrings` is constant, is to simply move it to an instance variable within this class (assuming that the code that does issue this dynamic query is in another method of the class).

Comment: Sometimes the scope can get confused though, so it's usually better to return a query locator instead of a string, if possible. Also, you might want to edit your answer, I'm not sure "an easy fox" is applicable here.

Comment: @David Reed. I have added a simple point that I am not mentioned in the question that the calling method of this method is in a different class. So for that use case you have to define the Set as Instance variable inside the calling class and pass it as a parameter in the calling class method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String buildQueryString(Object_Rule__mdt ObjectRule, Datetime createdDatetime) {
      List<String> fields = new List<String>();
      Set<String> statusSetStrings = new Set<String>{'Pending', 'Processing'};
      this.query = 'SELECT ';
      for (Field_Rule__mdt fieldRules : ObjectRule.Field_Rules__r) {
        fields.add(fieldRules.Field_Name__c);
      }

      this.query += String.join(fields, ', ');
      this.query += ', ' + ContactIdField__c;
      this.query += ' FROM ' + ObjectRule.SObject__c;
      this.query += ' WHERE ' + ObjectRule.ContactIdField__c + ' IN ';
      this.query += '(SELECT Contact__c FROM Request__c'; 
      this.query += ' WHERE Status__c IN (' + String.join(statusSetStrings, ', ') + ') ';
      this.query += ' AND CreatedDate < :createdDatetime)';

    return this.query;
}
```

Your dynamic query can't 'see' the bind variable you're trying to reference . You should parse your set of strings into the query string instead. Something like the above snippet should work (string assembly split for ease-of-reading).

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You have to use Set or List to query records in 'IN' clause. How can you do it using the join String?

Comment: @Hariprasath `WHERE FIELD IN ('A','B')` is perfectly normal SOQL. You only need to use a Set or List if you are binding to it.

Comment: Ah my bad missed to see the IN in the query.

Comment: @Dan Wareing your answer also we can try and correct but I accept the detailed explained one.

Comment: @Hariprasath - of course, it's excellent!